# create json data in android for call logs

Tags: android, json

I want to create a json format  for my call logs details like the below and send it to the server in android  :

{"Calllogs":{

"logdata":[

{
"id":"9791",
"number":"+919122185954",
"duration":"0",
"types":"3",
"date":"1425887846182",
"name":"ww"}
,
{

"id":"9790",
"number":"+91712222777",
"duration":"32",
"types":"1",
"date":"1425880324221",
"name":"Dpika"}
:
:
:
:

]}}

but when i use the below code to fetch all the call logs details in json format and send it to the server , i am getting a very unusual error like when i send 30 contacts it is working fine but when i fetch more than that i am getting an error ????

CODE:

```
public void GetCallLogs()
  {
        JSONObject main= new JSONObject();
        JSONObject calllogs = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray logs = new JSONArray();
      Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"),null, null, null, "_ID DESC");

        cur.moveToFirst();

        int nameColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
        int numberColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duretion = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        int type = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int id = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID);

        int i=0;

        JSONObject studenti = new JSONObject();
        while (!cur.isAfterLast() && i < 50) {

            String name = cur.getString(nameColumn);
            String number = cur.getString(numberColumn);
            String date = cur.getString(dateColumn);
            String duration = cur.getString(duretion);
            String types = cur.getString(type);
            String ids = cur.getString(id);



            try {
                studenti.put("id", ids);
                studenti.put("name",name);
                studenti.put("date", date);
                studenti.put("duration", duration);
                studenti.put("types", types);
                studenti.put("number", number);

                Log.d("HERE IN FETCHCALL", "name"+name);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            logs.put(studenti);


            studenti = new JSONObject();



            cur.moveToNext();
        i++;
        }

        try {
            calllogs.put("logdata", logs);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


      try {
        main.put("Calllogs", calllogs);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }
```

Comment: Firstly update your post and describe problem. Now you added only code nothing more

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not giving enough info, I must have to assume that you are wanting to create a JSON file with your following code:

`name
number
date
duration
types
ids`

I have used this [link](https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to create `JSON` files for my `ListView`.